# ASP.Net - HTTP to HTTPS Rewrite Module Not Working When the Character '&' Exists in the URL String

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

My URL HTTP to HTTPS rewrite does not work when there is the character '&' in the URL.

A 410 page not found results.

An example that results in a 410 is...

http://curtainsmadesimple.co.uk/1062/Rapture-&-Wright/Rapture-&-Wright-Collection-Roomshots

OR

http://www.curtainsmadesimple.co.uk/1062/Rapture-&-Wright/Rapture-&-Wright-Collection-Roomshots

However if the '&' is replaced by 'and' in the above URLs the page loads correctly.

I have two rules to rewrite HTTP to HTTPS. One is where there is a non www and the other if there is a www

```
  <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.curtainsmadesimple\.co\.uk$" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://www.curtainsmadesimple.co.uk/{R:1}" />
```

```
  <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It will work I believe. This is working for me.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
     <clear />
         <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
               <conditions>
                  <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
               </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
         </rule>
  </rules>
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. What about if the URL does not have the www prefix?

Comment: What about if the URL does not have the www prefix i.e. http://curtainsmadesimple.co.uk/1062/Rapture-&-Wright/Rapture-&-Wright-Collection-Roomshots?

Comment: @willcms are you using SSL? I do not see that.

Comment: Yes I have an SSL. I tried using your rule but my website returned a 500 error. I have since returned to the original two rules.

Comment: @willcms In which section are you adding?

Comment: @willcms try to add in '<system.webServer>'

Comment: Yes its in the following section in the <system.webserver> which points to a separate rules file...    <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="rewriteMaps.config"></rewriteMaps>
      <!--<rules configSource="rewriteRules.config"></rules>-->
       <rules configSource="rewriteRulesHTTPS.config"></rules>
      <!--<outboundRules configSource="rewriteOutboundRules.config"></outboundRules>-->
    </rewrite>

Comment: I did comment out my two HTTP to HTTPS rerwite rules and put your rule in my rewriteRulesHTTPS.config file (referenced from my web.config file). I cannot just test using only your rule and none of my other rules.

Comment: Could you put them in web.config file? @willcms

Comment: Can you explain how I can do this given what I currently have is the following... <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="rewriteMaps.config"></rewriteMaps>
      <rules configSource="rewriteRulesHTTPS.config"></rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

Comment: @willcms still error? Did you add them in web.config file?

Comment: I can not explain on your given code. Sorry.. @willcms

Comment: Thank you for your help but will wait to see if anyone else gets back to me.